# Cannot update model of directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't understand why if I add more elements to my array inside of a controller of one directive, are not showed in the view and worst is that if I print my model it doesn't show the newest elements added

Here's how I defined my directives

```
angular.module('example',[]);

angular.module('example').directive('documentUpload', function() {

function link($scope, $element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
    $element.find('input[type="file"]').on('change', function (){
        $scope.submitFile(this);    
    });
}

return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'document-upload.html',
    controller: function($scope,$element) {
        $scope.files = [{ name : "blah", src: "blah" }];
        $scope.submitFile = function(file,container) {
            var currentFile = file.files[0];
            var reader  = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function(){
                $scope.files.push({
                    name: currentFile.name,
                    src : reader.result
                });
                console.log($scope.files);
                console.log($scope.example);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(currentFile);
        };
    },
    alias: 'document',
    link: link
}

}).directive('imageFiles', function($compile) {
    return {
        scope: {
            file: "="
        },
        template: '<img ng-model="file" ng-src="file.src" alt="file.name" class="img-responsive"/>'
    }
});
```

And if I tried to see the model in the view is not showing the newest element added,

```
<div class="row">
<pre>{{ files }}</pre>
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" ng-submit="submit(document)">
      <input type="file" name="file" ng-model="document.file"/>           
    </form>
</div>
<div class="row" ng-repeat="file in files" image-files>
```

Here's a live [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/dt7NZ54bgg0OkSuiOd2m?p=preview)

Comment: Your function that changes it is never called. I would look into a better way to call that function.

Comment: that's true is not running in the example let me fixed that (but is working in my environment

Comment: fixed.. now is trigger the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so here is what is happening. Since you are using reader.onloadend which is an external function or plugin, whatever it is. It is missing the internal angular digest process.

This is a case where you need to add $scope.$apply() after you push to the array.

```
$scope.files.push({
   name: currentFile.name,
   src : reader.result
});
$scope.$apply();
```

This forces angular to refresh itself.

Here is a working plunker just to be safe.

http://plnkr.co/edit/w3u3VWMC9e8h1L0Bhkuh?p=preview

Comment: Awesome, I was tired and as always is something... :D good, also is not a plugin is just the FileAPI nothing else